# how to raise exception in the ocaml code?

Tags: ocaml

`bigint` as data type of the form (sign, base, integer list) like 35 in base of 7 is 
(Pos, 7, [0;5]).
now we need to convert this bigint to integer that is if we put `(Pos, 7, [0;5])` then we get answer as 35. i dont understand that  how to raise exception on the cases that no. in list are greater than base or base is 0 or most significant digit is zero -> [7;3;4;0].
thus i wrote:

```
#type sign = Pos | Neg;;
#type digitseq = int list;;
#type bigint = sign * int * digitseq;;
#let check_bigint (sign, r, l1) = match l1 with
    [] -> true
  | [0] -> false
  | x::xs -> if (x >= r) then false else check_bigint (sign, r, xs)
;;
#let rec bigint2int (sign, r, l1) =
  if (check_bigint (sign, r, l1) = false) then
    raise exception Invalid_input
  else
    (match l1 with
       [] -> 0
     | x::xs -> if (sign = Pos) then
                  x+r*(bigint2int (sign, r, xs))
                else (-x)+r*(bigint2int (sign, r, xs)))
;;
```

i am getting a syntax error in else just before (match l1...
please tell whats wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax is `raise Invalid_input` instead of `raise exception Invalid_input`.

Note that `#` is not part of the program and that you should not include it in the OCaml snippets that you post. You have another problem, in that you forgot the `rec` in the definition of `check_bigint`. This is another pitfall of using the toplevel. You might as well start using the compiler now.

```
type sign = Pos | Neg;;
type digitseq = int list;;
type bigint = sign * int * digitseq;;
exception Invalid_input;;
let rec check_bigint (sign, r, l1) = match l1 with
    [] -> true
  | [0] -> false
  | x::xs -> if (x >= r) then false else check_bigint (sign, r, xs)
;;
let rec bigint2int (sign, r, l1) =
  if (check_bigint (sign, r, l1) = false) then
    raise Invalid_input
  else
    (match l1 with
       [] -> 0
     | x::xs -> if (sign = Pos) then
                  x+r*(bigint2int (sign, r, xs))
                else (-x)+r*(bigint2int (sign, r, xs)))
;;
```

Answer (score 3):

Keyword `exception` is used to define an exception.

For example, `exception Invalid_input` define the exception first, then later on, you can `raise Invalid_input`.

Notice that, sometimes for conveniences, you can use `failwith "Invalid_input"` to raise built-in exception `Failure` with the given string.